# How can get the iOS UUID in a Flutter project?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying to integrate get UUid using Ad Support into my Flutter project using the following Swift code:

```
import AdSupport
import Flutter
import UIKit

public class FlutterAndroididPlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flutter_IosUUid", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = FlutterAndroididPlugin()
    registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
  }

  public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
    switch call.method {
    case "getPlatformVersion":
      result("iOS " + UIDevice.current.systemVersion)
    case "getAdvertisingIdentifier":
      let identifierManager = ASIdentifierManager.shared()
      if identifierManager.isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled {
        let deviceId = identifierManager.advertisingIdentifier.uuidString
          result(deviceId)
      }  
      else {
        result(nil)
      }
    default:
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried running sudo pod install, but I still get the same error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

I'm using Flutter version 2.10.5.
I'm using Xcode version 13.4.1.
I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.
I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: " but I still get the same error." What error?

Comment: Unable to find a specification for `AdSupport` depended